# How to install Java 11 in TeamCity?

Tags: java, docker, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm a junior developer introducing unit testing to a project using SBT with Java 11. In my team of 3, they never wrote any kind of unit testing.

We are planning to start it now.

We have a self-hosted TeamCity CI/CD setup for unit testing. The default TeamCity runner agent (Docker) uses Java 17.

How can I install Java 11 within the existing runner or create a new runner with Java 11?

Installed runner using this

```bash
docker run -e SERVER_URL="http://<My self hosted server URL>:8111" jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

Comment: Java 17 can build and execute Java 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to install Java 11 in TeamCity via Docker :**

1. Create a `Docker` file.

   ```
   FROM jetbrains/teamcity-server:latest
   RUN apt-get update && \
       apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk
   ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
   RUN update-alternatives --set java $JAVA_HOME/bin/java
   EXPOSE 8111
   CMD ["/opt/teamcity/bin/teamcity-server.sh", "run"]
   ```
2. Build the Docker file via below command:

   ```bash
   docker build -t teamcity-with-java11
   ```
3. Run the Teamcity container via below command:

   ```bash
   docker run -it --name teamcity-instance -p 8111:8111 teamcity-with-java11
   ```

Once the container is up and running, try to access `TeamCity` via http://localhost:8111.

Comment: Thanks Solved , but using teamcity-agent docker image